# Why is number of moves to exchange boxes into the correct position always an even number?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic

I have a little game in which you start with a 12x3 grid of squares of different colors. The goal is to move the squares in the correct shade order (no squares are in the right position at the beginning, you always start with the same order). The squares are moved by switching any two squares (not necessarily next to each other).
After collecting a lot of data I realized all results where even numbers. Any idea of the mathematical reason behind this?

Comment: Probably something in how you make the initial shuffle.

Comment: If your initial shuffle is a swap shuffle (randomly picking 2 distinct elements and swapping them) and you do it an even number of times, then it will always take an even number of swaps to sort.  Someone who studies group theory can probably explain why better than me.

Comment: It depends on the number of inversions in the initial sequence, see [Parity of the Number of Swaps of Swap-Based Sorting Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62007208/5821790) on stack overflow.